# How to connect mywebsite to Oracle cloud?

Tags: php, oracle, web, oracle11g, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I am using this code for connect my website to oracle cloud database

```
$db = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOSTNAME)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DBNAME)))';
$db_charset = 'AL32UTF8';

$c = oci_connect("USERNAME","PASSWORD",$db, $db_charset);
```

I cannot connect to oracle cloud

I want to know what steps to connect my website to using tables in oracle cloud.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure you have the SID, not the SERVICE_NAME?

Comment: Please post the error messages you get...

Comment: the code is right but I can't access to oracle cloud by using this code from my website

Comment: I am try to use adodb5 $adodb = NewADOConnection($this->driver_name); also i can't access to use DB

Comment: Would be helpful if you could post the log. Since I assume you are trying to connect from a PHP application on your local computer to a DB instance on Oracle Cloud, perhaps the issue is with the port not being exposed on your Oracle Database instance. Have you checked that?

Comment: You very likely need to change the access rules to allow for this